# Library Tools Options Not Clickable

Tags: web-part

I have come across this issue a couple of times now, when i go into the web parts page under site settings, i cant click on the documents or Library tabs under Library tools. I want to get into these so i can download one of the web parts.

Also if i try and edit the page, all the options are greyed out. Any ideas what might have caused and how I can fix this? I'm using Sharepoint 2010

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out what this was, i was adding some custom java that was overiding the page onload events, i put this into the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames array and its working again now

Answer (score 0):

Check what permissions you have within the site. Since the options are greyed out while you edit the page, the options may not be enabled for your permission level. Try elevating your permissions contacting an administrator and you will get the options enabled.

Comment: i dont think its a permissions thing i'm logged in with the admin account. Could the page be locked for editing/checked out?